# Convert text file to json file using batch script

Tags: batch, json, textfiles

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


echo { >>post.json
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1  delims==" %%a in (hardware.txt) do (
    set temp=%%a
    set res=%%b
    call :Trim result !res!
    call :Trim tem !temp!
    for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("!result!") do (
        set var=%%i
        echo !var!
        if defined var (
            echo "!tem!" : "!result!", >> post.json
        ) else (
            echo "!tem!" : !result!, >> post.json
        ) 
    )
)
echo } >> post.json

:Trim
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Params=%*
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ("!Params!") do EndLocal & set %1=%%b
exit /b
```

I made a for loop which reads from a file named hardware.txt which has information in the following format:

```
os = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro  
osVersion = 10.0.19042  
username = desktop-ujer9ka\arron 
brand = ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.  
model = X556UR  
ram = 12  
storage = 934 
macAddress = 00:FF:F7:29:ED:06
```

I get json in the following format:

```
{ 
"os" : "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro" ,
"osVersion" : "10.0.19042" ,
"username" : "desktop-ujer9ka\arron" ,
"brand" : "ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC." ,
"model" : "X556UR" ,
"macAddress" : "00:FF:F7:29:ED:06" ,
"processor" : "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz" ,
}
```

In the second for loop else condition is not executed. If there is any other easy way please let me know or if anyone can help with me wit this would be great.
I need the second for loop because i want to check if the variable is a number or not as i need a number in the json.
I also don't know how to remove the last comma after th string so as to make a proper json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bath
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0" 

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

for /f %%N in ('find /c "=" ^<.\hardware.txt')do set "_n=%%~N" && (
   for /l %%L in (1,1,%%~N)do set /p _line_%%~L=)<.\hardware.txt

%:^(
for /L %%L in (1 1 %_n%)do for %%G in ("     ","    ","   ","  ")do set "_line_%%~L=!_line_%%~L:%%~G=!"
for /L %%L in (1 1 %_n%)do if "!_line_%%~L:~-1!"==" " (set "_line_%%~L=!_line_%%~L:~0,-1!" & goto %:^()

for /L %%L in (1 1 %_n%)do for /f usebackq^tokens^=1-2*delims^=^= %%i in (`
    call echo\!_line_%%~L!`)do set "_line_%%~L="%%~i@%%~j""

>>.\post.json (
    for /L %%L in (2 1 %_n%)do if %%~L equ 2 (
        echo\^{
        echo\    !_line_%%~L: @ =" : "!,
       )else if %%~L neq %_n% (
        echo\    !_line_%%~L: @ =" : "!,
       )else (
        echo\    !_line_%%~L: @ =" : "!
        echo\^}
       )
    ) && endlocal
```

---

I am considering:

1. You need to skip the first line of your hardware.txt file, because
   your `For /F` looping command is using `skip=1`, so the `For /L`
   loop starts at `2` not `1` , so also "skipped" a line/variable of
   the file.
2. Most of your strings in the hardware file were fetched by scripts I
   assume I used like the `wmic` command and redirected to the file,
   and consequently, this is where the extra spaces at the end of the
   line came to be added at the end of lines/string.
3. I didn't understand (failure of my limited english), what you need
   to do where you want/need to identify numbers, any additional
   explanation may adapt the answer to meet you at this point as well.
4. Even though I already assume that your commands were obtained
   through the use of `wmic`, also not knowing what content to jump on
   the first line or its origin, I am adding another bat that gets the
   information similar to your hardware.txt file however, already
   redirecting the output in .json file format
5. Item **4.** definitely doesn't answer that part of your question *If
   there is any other easy way please let me know*, forgive me, some
   things I prefer to re-do to facilitate handling in future
   edits/adaptations
6. When using `find "="` in the first `For /F` loop, I'm counting the
   lines that have "=", and considering/using a file equal to your
   hardware.txt posted in your question, so I suggest that you test
   with the same lines and respective amount of lines posted in the
   question, if there are differences, please let me know...
7. I suppose the use pointed out in item **6.** may make `skip=1`
   obsolete/unproductive, so I am adding a complete code below and as
   well as the suggestion code to get the strings without additional
   spaces at the end of the lines...

---

- With no `skip=1` in `For` loops:

```bath
:: for /L %%L in (2 1 %_n%)do if %%~L equ 2 ()else if()else()...
::                ↓                       ↓
:: for /L %%L in (1 1 %_n%)do if %%~L equ 1 ()else if()else()...
```

---

```bath
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

if not defined _fjson (call setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
     set "_fjson=post.json" & call "%~f0" >"%~dp0\!_fjson!"
     timeout /t 05 | type "!_fjson!" & endlocal & goto :eof
    );= else <con call set "_spc="     ","    ","   ","  ""
     
for /f %%N in ('find /c "=" ^<.\hardware.txt')do set "_n=%%~N" & (
     for /l %%L in (1,1,%%~N)do set /p _line_%%~L=)<.\hardware.txt
 
%:^(
for /L %%L in (1,1,%_n%)do for %%G in (;%_spc%)do (set "_line_%%~L=!_line_%%~L:%%~G=!"
     if "!_line_%%~L:~-1!"==" " call set "_line_%%~L=!_line_%%~L:~0,-1!" && goto %:^()
 
for /L %%L in (1,1,%_n%)do for /f usebackq^tokens^=1-2*delims^=^= %%i in (
    `call echo\!_line_%%~L!`)do call set "_line_%%~L=    "%%~i@%%~j"" && (
         if %%~L equ 1 (echo\^{&& <con: call echo\!_line_%%~L: @ =" : "!^
            )else if not %%~L equ %_n% (call echo\!_line_%%~L: @ =" : "!^,
            )else call echo\!_line_%%~L: @ =" : "! && echo\^});=
```

---

- Get strings in `.json` format and no extra spaces at the end of the line

```bath
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

:: var line_1 ::  os = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
title <nul & title set variable line_1
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^> %%i in (`
     wmic os get caption /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
   `)do set "_line_1="os" : "%%~i""

:: var line_2 :: osVersion = 10.0.19042
title <nul & title set variable line_2
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^> %%i in (`
     wmic os get version /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
   `)do set "_line_2="osVersion" : "%%~i""

:: var line_3 :: username = desktop-ujer9ka\arron 
title <nul & title set variable line_3
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^> %%i in (`
     wmic /node:. computersystem get username /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
   `)do set "_line_3="username" : "%%i""

:: var line_4 :: brand = ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
title <nul & title set variable line_4
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     wmic csproduct get vendor /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
   `)do set "_line_4="brand" : "%%~i""

:: var line_5 :: model = X556UR
title <nul & title set variable line_5
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     wmic csproduct get name /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
   `)do set "_line_5="model" : "%%~i""

:: var line_6 :: ram = 12
title <nul & title set variable line_6
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     wmic computersystem get totalphysicalmemory /format:xml ^|find "VALUE"`)do for /f %%G in ('
     mshta "vbscript:Execute("createobject(""scripting.filesystemobject""^).GetStandardStream(1^).write(Round(%%i/1073741824^)^):close")"^|more
   ')do set "_line_6="ram" : "%%~G""

:: var line_7 :: storage = 934
title <nul & title set variable line_7
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     wmic logicaldisk where Caption^="C:" get Size /format:xml^|find "VALUE"`)do for /f %%G in ('
     mshta "vbscript:Execute("createobject(""scripting.filesystemobject""^).GetStandardStream(1^).write(Round(%%i/1073741824^)^):close")"^|more
   ')do set "_line_7="storage" : "%%G""

:: var line_8 macAddress = 00:FF:F7:29:ED:06
title <nul & title set variable line_8
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
     wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where "PNPDeviceID like '%%%%PCI%%%%' and NetConnectionStatus='2' and AdapterTypeID='0'" get MacAddress /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
   `)do set "_line_8="macAddress" : "%%~i""

:: var line_9 :: processor = Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
title <nul & title set variable line_9
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^>^< %%i in (`
      wmic CPU get NAME /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
    `)do set "_line_9="processor" : "%%~i""

:: var lines 1-9 :: Writing lines from 1 to 9 in post.json file
title <nul & title write line 1-9 to file: .\post.json
>.\post.json (
    for /L %%L in (1 1 9)do for /f usebackq^delims^= %%i in (`
            "echo\    !_line_%%~L!"`)do if %%~L equ 1 (
             echo\^{ && echo\%%~i,)else if %%~L neq 9 (
             echo\%%~i,)else echo\%%~i&& echo\^}
            )

:: Checking lines_1-9 :: Checking file contents/lines on screen
title <nul & title Checking file contents/lines on screen
timeout /t 10 | type .\post.json & endlocal
```

---

- On my computer I get the output:

```bath
{
    "os" : "Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language",
    "osVersion" : "10.0.19043",
    "username" : "DESKTOP-JRRL1K6\DP",
    "brand" : "LENOVO",
    "model" : "80UH",
    "ram" : "20",
    "storage" : "447",
    "macAddress" : "5C:C9:D3:7E:B1:1C",
    "processor" : "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz"
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you have done `set var=%%`, the variable is defined - it's just empty.

To check for an empty variable :

```
IF [%1] == [] ...
IF "%~1" == "" ...
```

For more information see the post
[What is the proper way to test if a parameter is empty in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541767/what-is-the-proper-way-to-test-if-a-parameter-is-empty-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: Thanks, you indirectly solved my problem.